# How can escape spaces in directory names in a MANIFEST.in files?

Tags: python, setuptools

I've inherited some code that has directory names with embedded spaces, and I don't have the option of renaming the directory.  Let's say the name of the directory is "embedded spaces"

Now I'm trying to access some files from this directory in a MANIFEST.in file

I've tried the following:

```
recursive-include 'embedded spaces' *.dat
recursive-include "embedded spaces" *.dat
recursive-include embedded\ spaces *.dat
```

These all give errors something along the lines of "warning: no files found matching 'spaces' under directory 'embedded'

I have a workaround which is

```
recursive-include embedded* *.dat
```

but I was wondering if there's a less hackish way to encode spaces in MANIFEST.in directory names.

Comment: `recursive-include "embedded\ spaces *.dat"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it would appear not.  Inspecting the source of `distutils.filelist`, which does the work of parsing the `MANIFEST.in` shows that the line is split purely on whitespace to determine the action and its parameters

Here is the source (in python 2,7)

```
def _parse_template_line(self, line):
    words = line.split()
    action = words[0]

    ...

    if action in ('include', 'exclude',
                  'global-include', 'global-exclude'):
        ...
    elif action in ('recursive-include', 'recursive-exclude'):
        if len(words) < 3:
            raise DistutilsTemplateError, \
                  "'%s' expects <dir> <pattern1> <pattern2> ..." % action

        dir = convert_path(words[1])
        patterns = map(convert_path, words[2:])

    ...
```

Comment: It's not what I was hoping for, but it does answer the question.  I should have thought to check the source before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `recursive-include embedded?spaces *.dat`.

Comment: This is pretty much the same approach I'm using now, but I do like it better and will switch to this from my current workaround.